# Retrieve value from radioButtons in alertDialog

Tags: android

I want to retrive the value from the radio buttons. I am doing the below code. But when I click OK button of alert dialog my app is force closed. why is is so. A I not retriving the value properly

```
 final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true))
    {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
        final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

        final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);


    // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which)
            {
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();                   
                // find the radiobutton by returned id
                  final RadioButton  radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                    String radio_value = radioButton.getText().toString(); 
                    data_mode=Integer.parseInt(radio_value);

                 String value = userInput.getText().toString();
                 currentIntervalChoice=Integer.parseInt(value);

                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                 editor.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
                 editor.putInt("currentIntervalChoice", currentIntervalChoice);  
                 editor.putInt("data_mode", data_mode);
                 editor.commit();             
                 dialog.dismiss();
            }
              });
        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // show it
        alertDialog.show();     
    }
```

prompt.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type Interval : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
     </RadioGroup>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is your RadioGroup R.id.radioGroup1 inside the AlertDialog's View (PromptsView)? paste your layout XML.

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: is your `RadioButton` in AlertDialog?

Comment: yes radioButton is in AlertDialog

Comment: May be because you have not done as: `final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);` and at
`final RadioButton  radioButton = (RadioButton) promptsView.findViewById(selectedId);`

Comment: @user2310041 : if radioButton is in AlertDialog, you should check Pragnani answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RadioButton` is null and when you are trying to access it, it will throw `NullPointerException` so get your  `RadioButton` like this

```
 RadioButton  radioButton = (RadioButton)promptsView. findViewById(selectedId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your dialog cancelable:

```
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
```

Comment: I dont want it to be cancelable.

Answer (score 0):

try making these corrections:

`final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);`

and in `onClick();` `final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) promptsView.findViewById(selectedId);`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you get a NullpointerException when trying to use the selected radiobutton. If your activity class name is MyActivity, try something like this :

```
// find the radiobutton by returned id
final RadioButton  radioButton = (RadioButton) MyActivity.this.findViewById(selectedId);
```